# JQuery not working for radio button

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Group,

I have below code that isn't doing what I intend it to do. Not sure what am I missing. Can you please help? I would like an alert to flash as soon as radio button is clicked by the user. However, nothing is happening when the radio button is clicked.

```
<HTML>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">


$('#amtopts input').on('change', function() {
   alert($('input[name=amount_r]:checked', '#amtopts').val()); 
});

var donateamt = document.getElementsByName('amount_r');
var donateamt_value;

function GetDonationAmt() {
    for(var i = 0; i < donateamt.length; i++){
        if(donateamt[i].checked){
            donateamt_value = donateamt[i].value;
            alert("Donation Amount is "+donameamt_value); 
            break;
        }
    }
 }
 );
 </script>
 <body>
 <h1>Donate Now</h1>
 <p></p>    
  Amount: Amount: <form id="amtopts"><input type="radio" id="amount_r" name="amount_r" value="50"> 50<input type="radio" id="amount_r" name="amount_r" value="75"> 75<input type="radio" id="amount_r" name="amount_r" value="100" > 100<input type="radio" id="amount_r" name="amount_r" value="150"> 150</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You can not have code inside a script tag if you are using the src attribute.:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
code
</script>
```

you have to do it like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
code
</script>
```

```js
$('#amtopts input').on('change', function() {
  alert($('input[name=amount_r]:checked', '#amtopts').val());
});

var donateamt = document.getElementsByName('amount_r');
var donateamt_value;

function GetDonationAmt() {
  for (var i = 0; i < donateamt.length; i++) {
    if (donateamt[i].checked) {
      donateamt_value = donateamt[i].value;
      alert("Donation Amount is " + donameamt_value);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>Donate Now</h1>
  <p></p>
  Amount: Amount:
  <form id="amtopts"><input type="radio" id="amount_r" name="amount_r" value="50"> 50<input type="radio" id="amount_r" name="amount_r" value="75"> 75<input type="radio" id="amount_r" name="amount_r" value="100"> 100<input type="radio" id="amount_r" name="amount_r" value="150">    150</form>
```

As RoryMcCrossan says, it would be a good idea to wrap your code in document ready:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    code
})
</script>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I agree.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the onclick event:

```
$("input[name='amount_r']").click(function(){
alert('You clicked radio1!');
    alert($('input:radio[name=amount_r]:checked').val());


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to modify your script tag for j query API, you don't put your custom J query inside same script tag of j query API. see below code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And i minimize the code using of class instead of name/id please follow the code you will surely get the flash message.

HTML :

```
    <form id="amtopts">
  <input type="radio" id="amount_r" name="amount_r" class="amt" value="50"> 50
  <input type="radio" id="amount_r" name="amount_r" class="amt" value="75"> 75
  <input type="radio" id="amount_r" name="amount_r" class="amt" value="100" > 100
  <input type="radio" id="amount_r" name="amount_r" class="amt" value="150"> 150
  </form>
```

J query :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.amt').click(function() {
      alert($(this).val())
    })
 })
 </script>
```